# VBA code to remove spaces when pasting to Notepad

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need the tabs between the words and values removed when pasting data to Notepad (from copying from Excel).  I already have the vba code to open Notepad and paste, but only to paste with the tabs (spaces).  Please help!

```
Range("A1:EX100").Copy
Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
SendKeys "^V"
```

Comment: Use the Find/Replace feature. Assuming an English OS: (Ctrl+H,ALt+N,{TAB},Alt+A) -- ^H, %N, {TAB}, %A

Comment: Why not create a macro that saves it as csv file with space as the delimiter. When writing the file change extension to .txt and that will open in Notepad easily?